# undefined method 'each' Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-view-controller

Apologies in advance, I am a newbie trying to get my head around rails.

My View at the bottom works when I use:

```
def show
@posts = Post.all
end
```

However in my controller I now have:

```
def show
@posts = Post.find_by_category_id params[:id];
end
```

In my view I have

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
<%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

Some please explain why I get this error. What should I use. category_id is a foreign key on the Post table.

Answer (score 3):

Look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

```
Finds the first record matching the specified conditions
```

find_by_ will return only one post, not a collection. So you are not able to use each.

Comment: You're the best, that link is exactly what I needed. I am now using @posts = Post.where("category_id = " + params[:id]).all;

Answer (score -1):

try

```
def show
  @posts = Post.all.find_by_category_id params[:id];
end
```

Comment: why the semicolon? `find_by_category_id` is deprecated as of Rails 4.1 , use `find_by(category_id: params[:id])` instead.

Comment: I just copy pasted original code, semicolon was there and it was not his original problem